# How to get names and values of cookies from PHP

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, e-commerce

I'm coding an e-commerce website that uses cookies to transfer information from the product page to the cart.

`$_COOKIE` has all of the cookies for a certain page put into an array, with the name of the cookie and the the value of the cookie. Example:

`array(2) { ["0_USB_Keyboard"]=> string(6) "$19.99" ["0_Alarm_Clock_Radio"]=> string(6) "$14.99" }`

How can I take each cookie name and put them in an new array, so they can be used elsewhere. And how can I put each cookie value in an new array, so that they too can be used else where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**// Edit**
Use `array_keys` and `array_values`
Example:

```
$array = array( 
 "0_USB_Keyboard" => "$19.99", 
 "0_Alarm_Clock_Radio" => "$14.99"
);

print_r(array_keys($array));
print_r(array_values($array));
```

Output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0_USB_Keyboard
    [1] => 0_Alarm_Clock_Radio
)
Array
(
    [0] => $19.99
    [1] => $14.99
)
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: [Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please edit your answer and add enough information that it can stand on its own.

Comment: Or as you now have 50+ points post this as a comment, as that is all it really is

Comment: @Chris well I guess we are going to loose this one

Comment: @Chris Edited. Now using example

Answer (score 0):

For a readable output use this

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_COOKIE, TRUE) . '</pre>';
```

then use this to add it to another Array

```
<?php
// for save coding
if(isset($_COOKIE) && !empty($_COOKIE)){
    foreach($_COOKIE AS $keyName => $valueOfKey){
        echo 'Debug Output: Key:' . $keyName . '|' . $valueOfKey . '<br>';
    }
}else{
echo 'Error, $_COOKIE not set or empty';
}
?>
```